# Query not returning the correct result for SUM based on NULL value

Tags: sql, mysql

I am not very good at queries and I am having an issue. Let's go to the point:
I have these three tables

```
CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER_INVOICE (
  SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
  FINALISED_STOCK TINYINT(1)
);

CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE (
  SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE_UID BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY,
  SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER VARCHAR(20),
  PURCHASE_ORDER_LINE_UID BIGINT(20),
  PRODUCT_UID BIGINT(20),
  FOREIGN KEY (SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER) REFERENCES SUPPLIER_INVOICE(SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER)
);

CREATE TABLE RECEIVED (
  RECEIVED_UID INT(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  ISBN VARCHAR(13),
  SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER VARCHAR(50),
  RECEIVED_QUANTITY INT(10),
  FOREIGN KEY (SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER) REFERENCES SUPPLIER_INVOICE(SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER)
);
```

1. Firstly, when I run this `SELECT * FROM RECEIVED WHERE ISBN = '9781838776329' AND SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER = 88873733;`   I have 121 different records and all of them have RECEIVED_QUANTITY = 1.
2. Secondly, when I run this command `SELECT * FROM SUPPLIER_INVOICE WHERE SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER = 88873733;` I have only one record as a result, which is:

```
SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER  FINALISED_STOCK
88873733                 0
```

3. Thirdly, when I run this command `SELECT * WHERE SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER = 88873733 AND SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE.PRODUCT_UID = 51689207;`
   I have two records as a result, and they are:

```
SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE_UID,  SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER,  PURCHASE_ORDER_LINE_UID,  PRODUCT_UID
18693389                88873733                  30669703                  51689207
18736917                88873733                  NULL              51689207
```

4. Also if I run

```
SELECT SUPPLIER_INVOICE.SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER, SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE.PURCHASE_ORDER_LINE_UID, SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE.PRODUCT_UID, SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE.RECEIVED_QUANTITY
FROM
SUPPLIER_INVOICE, SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE
WHERE
SUPPLIER_INVOICE.SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER = SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE.SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER
AND SUPPLIER_INVOICE.FINALISED_STOCK = 0
AND SUPPLIER_INVOICE.WAREHOUSE_UID = 1
AND SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE.PRODUCT_UID = 51689207;
```

I have two records as a result, and they are:

```
SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER    PURCHASE_ORDER_LINE_UID   PRODUCT_UID    RECEIVED_QUANTITY
88873733               30669703              51689207       120
88873733               NULL                  51689207       1
```

5. So, what I am trying to do is sum up `RECEIVED.RECEIVED_QUANTITY` for the records where `PURCHASE_ORDER_LINE_UID = NULL` and also based on other conditions as you can see below. I believe the result of the query below should be 1, but for some reason it returns 121.

```
SELECT
    SUM(RECEIVED.RECEIVED_QUANTITY) AS total
FROM 
    RECEIVED
    JOIN SUPPLIER_INVOICE ON RECEIVED.SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER = SUPPLIER_INVOICE.SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER
    JOIN SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE ON RECEIVED.SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER = SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE.SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER
WHERE
    SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE.PURCHASE_ORDER_LINE_UID IS NULL
    AND SUPPLIER_INVOICE.FINALISED_STOCK = 0
    AND SUPPLIER_INVOICE.SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER = '88873733'
    AND SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE.PRODUCT_UID = 51689207
    AND RECEIVED.ISBN = '9781838776329';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do following and see what the output is:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    RECEIVED
    JOIN SUPPLIER_INVOICE ON RECEIVED.SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER = SUPPLIER_INVOICE.SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER
    JOIN SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE ON RECEIVED.SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER = SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE.SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER
WHERE
    SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE.PURCHASE_ORDER_LINE_UID IS NULL
    AND SUPPLIER_INVOICE.FINALISED_STOCK = 0
    AND SUPPLIER_INVOICE.SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NUMBER = '88873733'
    AND SUPPLIER_INVOICE_LINE.PRODUCT_UID = 51689207
    AND RECEIVED.ISBN = '9781838776329';
```

(Note that we do not have your data and some of your queries are missing `FROM` clause)